# Objective-C Object Memory Allocation

Tags: objective-c

After writing years of Objective-C code, (sadly :-( ) I got myself confused today. Still too much to learn. Please see the following code snippet:

```
NSString *string1 = @"A string";
char cString[] = "A string";
NSString *string2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:cString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *string3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:cString length:sizeof(cString) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"String Pointers:\nstring1: %p\nstring2: %p\nstring3: %p\n\n", string1, string2, string3);
NSLog(@"String Hashes:\nstring1: %lu\nstring2: %lu\nstring3: %lu\n\n", string1.hash, string2.hash, string3.hash);

NSNumber *number1 = @1;
NSNumber *number2 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];
NSNumber *number3 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:1];
NSLog(@"Number Pointers:\nnumber1: %p\nnumber2: %p\nnumber3: %p\n\n", number1, number2, number3);
NSLog(@"Number Hashes:\nnumber1: %lu\nnumber2: %lu\nnumber3: %lu\n\n", number1.hash, number2.hash, number3.hash);
```

And the following output:

```
2017-10-25 23:55:24.572 ObjC[29888:303] String Pointers:
string1: 0x1000010a0
string2: 0x100109930
string3: 0x10010bcb0

2017-10-25 23:55:24.574 ObjC[29888:303] String Hashes:
string1: 10100169157824900864
string2: 10100169157824900864
string3: 8311704865341864449

2017-10-25 23:55:24.574 ObjC[29888:303] Number Pointers:
number1: 0x187
number2: 0x187
number3: 0x1c7

2017-10-25 23:55:24.575 ObjC[29888:303] Number Hashes:
number1: 2654435761
number2: 2654435761
number3: 2654435761
```

I have the following questions:

1. Is `string1` statically allocated, and other objects (`string2`, `string3`, `number1`, `number2`, and `number3`) dynamically allocated?
2. Why do `number1`, `number2` have the same pointer address if they are both dynamically allocated but `number3` doesn't have the same? (They all represent a number object which has a value of 1.)
3. Why these three string objects have the same (I suppose?) string value but only the first two has the same hash value?
4. What happens when invoking `-isEqual:` method? Is the pointer compared or the hash? Or depends on the type of the object? (Only limited to Foundation objects.)

Thank you!

Comment: For the first three: Implementation details, you don't have to worry about them (and the behavior may not necessarily be the same across versions of the OS). For #4: It depends on the object's implementation of `-isEqual:`, but generally speaking it should compare the contents rather than the pointer.

Comment: `string3` isn't what you think it is. `cString` includes a null terminator, so its size is one more than `strlen(cString)`. Since you're telling `NSString` to include that byte in the resulting string object, it does. (`NSString`s can contain null characters.) That's why `string3`'s hash is different from the other two; it's not equal to them.

Comment: @KenThomases: No, he doesn't, because `strlen()` doesn't count the null terminator.

Comment: First: The answer of your questions is highly implementation dependent, because initializers can return anything. It's not required that they always a new object. Especially for `NSString` and `NSNumber` they don't create always a new object. Another example is `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"A string"]`will just return `@"A string"`. Of course result of `isEqual`(and `hash`) depends on the class of the object. `NSObject`implements them based on the object's address. This is not very useful for `NSObject`and `NSNumber`. Theses classes compare the content (= value) of the objects.

Comment: @macmoonshine `isEqual:` usually compares addresses before comparing content. An object is equal to itself.

Comment: @Willeke: Yes, that's correct. But this is just an optimization for value comparison, but that doesn't contradict my statement. Objects having the same address **must** have the same value, because it's just the same object.

Comment: @macmoonshine Why is not very useful for `NSObject` and `NSNumber` to compare addresses? It's not enough but very fast if they are the same.

Comment: @Willeke: I never claimed that **only** the values were compared. An efficient implementation compares first the addresses, and only in the case of difference the values. But it makes no sense if you **only** compare addresses for these classes.

Comment: @macmoonshine, but he's not using `strlen()`, he's using `sizeof()`. That's my point.

Comment: @KenThomases: I see, you are right.

Comment: Thank you! I used the wrong function. strlen() gives the same hash.